# Custom popup, JSON, using setHTML to call upon more than 1 attribute

Tags: html, json, popup, mapbox

I'm trying to add (2) more lines of attributes to the popup and I hit a wall.  I think I will need to use the var function here but with little to no json experience, I'm struggling.  The code below works for (1) attribute to be called upon and displayed in my popup but like I mentioned above, I want to also display attributes [1] (STATE_NAME) and [2] (LINK).  Both are text fields with "LINK" being a URL to a webpage.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Side question, I want to overhaul the popup box to have different colored text and box.  How would one do this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Partner Practices</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<style>
.mapboxgl.popup {
    max-width: 600px;
    font: 16px/32px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RlcGhlbmdhemRpayIsImEiOiJjajdocnA1OWsxbHRrMnhxdWNuMnIwOWsyIn0.C2KZHzKkNE4pTqyfctgIPQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/stephengazdik/cj7hs1cs64vzz2rp999pdjx3w',
    center: [-100.04, 38.907],
    zoom: 3
});

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'States',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
            'type': 'vector',
            'url': 'mapbox://stephengazdik.3sk0q5rd'
        },
    'source-layer': 'AllStates-80jgla',
    layout: {
      visibility: 'visible'
    },
    paint: {
      'fill-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)'
    }
  });

    // When a click event occurs on a feature in the states layer, open a popup at the
    // location of the click, with description HTML from its properties.
    map.on('click', 'States', function (e) {
        new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
            .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.CURRENT_JO)
            .addTo(map);
    });

    // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the states layer.
    map.on('mouseenter', 'States', function () {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });

    // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
    map.on('mouseleave', 'States', function () {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```